# If $state.name('something') using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to check the state name and if it matches then do something?

Kind of like this:

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $state, $location, Auth) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
      if($state.name == "popular") {
         // Do Something
      } else {
         // Do Something else
      }
    });
  });
```

My goal is to redirect a user if they are logged in from one state to another state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could do: `$state.includes("myState")`

Answer (score 2):

Try `$state.current`

```
var currentLocation= $state.current

console.log(currentLocation);
```

Your currentLocation would look like this

```
Object {
    url: "/currentUrl", 
    templateUrl: "templates/currenthtml.html", 
    controller: "CurrentController", 
    name: "currentStateName"
}
```

then

```
if(yourCondition){
----Do something----
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions provided so far seem slightly flat and throw some scalability concerns if you aren't considering dynamic checks. Found myself doing a couple different options and there is probably an even better one, but here's a solution I used for checking dynamic ui-router data:

**Controller:**

```
$scope.dynData = $stateParams.dynData || ''; // default value
if($scope.dynData === '') {
    return $state.go('wherever');
} else {
    return $state.go('wherever');
}
```

Advanced check to keep child URLs from redirecting:

```
// Check dynData value doesn't exist and that we're not trying to load a child state
$scope.dynData = $stateParams.dynData;
if($scope.dynData === '' && $scope.$state.$current.path.length === 2) {
    $state.go('wherever');
// If passed, dynData exists and insure we're not trying to load a child state
} else if($scope.$state.$current.path.length === 2) {
    $state.go('wherever');
}
```

**Config**

```
.state('wherever', {
        url: '/videos/:dynData'
```

Likely a cleaner/clearer approach to this, but it's working great for me. You can log scope state and find a tons of things to check against, path length just happened to work for the logic I needed. **Adding the default value gives something better than 'undefined' to check against.**

Answer (score 0):

you can do `$state.current.name`